# I have two network cards, the SMTP sends from working network card

Tags: networking, routes, smtp

I have two network cards in my server, and both of them are connected, one is connected local and other one internet,

I have created a SMTP service, the problem is that the smtp only tries sending emails from the local network card.

I want it to try send emails from the internet network card, how can this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMTP does not know about network interface cards. The decisions is made by the operation system. What does your routing table look like, e.g. the output of "netstat -rn" on a Unix-like OS, and what is the IP address of the destination that your SMTP service tries to connect to?